# Randomly select words from multi-dimension array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multi-dimensional array and from where i want to choose 11 different words. Each word from different array index.

Here is the array link: [My multi-dimensional array](https://3v4l.org/hCrPj)

```
array (
  'w' => 
  array (
    0 => 'walls',
    1 => 'well',
    2 => 'why',
  ),
  'e' => 
  array (
    0 => 'end',
  ),      
  'a' => 
  array (
    0 => 'advantage',
    1 => 'afford',
    2 => 'affronting',
    3 => 'again',
    4 => 'agreeable',
    5 => 'ask',
    6 => 'at',
  ),
  'c' => 
  array (
    0 => 'children',
    1 => 'civil',
    2 => 'continual',
  )
);
```

My Desire Output:

```
From w => well
From e => end
From a => again
and so on.
```

**Output like:** `array(well, end, again, ...) as array.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Check Online](https://3v4l.org/JWIPr), and let me know.

using `shuffle` and `array_slice` you can get what you want.

A `shuffle` function makes your array random, and `array slice` slice 11 sub array from it. 
Array slice takes 3 argument, first one is the array, second one is the offset from where you want to start and last one how much you need to cut.

```
$words = array();
shuffle($result);
$res = array_slice($result, 0, 11);
foreach($res as $key => $value){
    shuffle($value);
    $words[] = $value[0];
}
print_r($words);
```

Comment: Thanks, This is so nice and pretty. I like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
$f = array_keys($result);  // grouping the indices, namely, the characters
$a = "";
for($c=0;$c<count($f);$c++){
    $a .= $f[$c];
} // grouping the indices stored in array $f to a string, $a
$words = array();
for($c=0;$c<11;$c++){
    $random = $a[rand(0,strlen($a)-1)];
    $k = $result[$random];
    // $k stores the array of the character index, stored in $result
    $random2 = rand(0,count($k)-1);
    $words[$c] = $k[$random2];
    // choose a word from a given character array
    $a = preg_replace("/".$random."/","",$a);
    // remove the character from $a to prevent picking words which start with the same character
}

print_r($words);
```

I've tested and it was proved working

https://3v4l.org/qi1VP

Comment: can you please share the example of test, like: in [https://3v4l.org/](https://3v4l.org/) where i share.

Comment: As per your request, URL was just added

Comment: Yes, awesome, its working, can you please add some description for better understand?

Comment: Some comments were added, hope you could understand the underlying principle

Comment: Thank you guys, But Frayne makes it very easy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this usin [array_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function :

**PHP**

```
$words = [];
$limit =  3; //Replace this with your limit, 11
$count = 0;
shuffle($array);
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $words[] = $value[array_rand($value)];
   $count++;
   if ($limit == $count) {
       break;
   }
}
```

[EvalIn](https://eval.in/575042)

Comment: Actually i need only 11 values as array like i said in my question, and `From ...w => ...` is only for understanding.

Comment: Its nice, but I have a problem in you script. I need random array values both from parent and child array. Like your array return sequentially. Is it possible to random parent also?

Comment: @user6364857 ca a letter come multiple time ?

Comment: from parent its only one, See the another answer he did it.

Comment: Just add shuffle function to randomize letter :)

Comment: Looks pretty good, can you please add some description how these works?

Comment: @user6364857 you're welcome sir :), could you valid the answer pls ?

Comment: The above only output 11 words according to the character index priorities only, instead of randomly. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thank you guys, But @Frayne makes it very easy. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your answer is good but the OP choose me, Why downvote man??? We are all helpers.

Comment: From the starting i follow you, you are increasing your daily reputation quickly, I must gives you support.

Comment: What does it means??